# html/css: Images slightly shifting on hover?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have set up a page with Wordpress in which thumbnails are displayed for all posts along with the respective post's title as a link to the post itself. The thumbnail images are links to the post as well.

The current version of the site can be seen here: http://udkdev.skopec.de/category/projekte/

Can someone explain to me, why all of the thumbnail images slightly shift when being hovered over? I thought I might have messed up something with the margins, the padding or the border, but after going through the site's CSS multiple times, I can't make out the mistake. Here's the code of the site itself along with the theme's CSS:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
</div>
<br>
<div class="wrapper-offset-fix wrapper-projekte">
<div class="projekte">

    <div class="button-group filters-button-group">
        <button class="active btn" id="all">alle</button>
        <button class="projekt-btn btn" id="category-wise-201516">WiSe 15/16</button>
        <button class="projekt-btn btn" id="category-sose-15">SoSe 15</button>
        <button class="projekt-btn btn" id="category-wise-201415">WiSe 14/15</button>
        <button class="projekt-btn btn" id="category-sose-14">SoSe 14</button>
        <button class="projekt-btn btn" id="category-wise-201314">WiSe 13/14</button>
        <button class="projekt-btn btn" id="category-sose-2013">SoSe 13</button>
        <button class="projekt-btn btn" id="category-wise-201213">WiSe 12/13</button>
        <button class="projekt-btn btn" id="category-sose-2012">SoSe 12</button>
    </div>


    <?php if (is_home()) {
    query_posts("cat=-3");
    } ?>

    <?php if (have_posts()): ?>
        <?php while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
        <div <?php post_class(); ?>>

            <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php 
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                the_post_thumbnail('large');
            } ?>
            </a>
        <!--<div class="meta">Tags: <?php the_tags( '', ', ', '<br />' ); ?> </div>-->
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else : ?>
        <h2>Couldn’t find any articles!</h2>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>

<script>
    var $btns = $('.btn').click(function() {

      if (this.id == 'all') {
        $('.projekte > .post').fadeIn(300);
      } else {
        var $el = $('.' + this.id).fadeIn(300);
        $('.projekte > .post').not($el).fadeOut(300);
      }
      $btns.removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    })
</script> 

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The CSS of the site's WP-Theme:

```
/* -------------------------------- Default WP classes */

* {

  /*cursor: url('kvscursor-01-4.png'), auto; */

  /*cursor: -webkit-image-set(url("kvscursor-01-4.png") 1x, url("kvscursor-01-4x2.png") 2x) 0 0, auto;*/
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%; }

body {
  font-size: 1.7em;
  line-height: 1.5;
  letter-spacing: 0.6px;
  /*  background: #6f6;*/
  color: #fff;
  background: #111;
  /*  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
    -ms-hyphens: auto; */
  }

a {
  color: white;
}


.wrapper {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 1em 1em 0 1em;
  position: relative; }

.wrapper h1 {
  font-family: 'News Gothic W01 Bold'; 

}

.wrapper a:link, a:visited {
  /*color: #fff;*/
  text-decoration: none; 
}

.post-navigation {
  /*display: flex;*/

  margin-top: 10em;
  max-width: 750px;
}

.post-navigation a, .top a, .back a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  border-bottom: 0px solid #ffffff;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
} 

.post-navigation a:hover, .top a:hover, .back a:hover {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);

  border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
} 

.menu a {
  color: white
}

.menu a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  /*padding-bottom: 0px;*/
}

.projekte a:link, a:visited {
  text-decoration: none; }

.projekte a: {
  /*border-bottom: 0px solid white;*/
}

.btn {
  margin-top: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  color: white;
}

.btn:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  padding-bottom: 1px;

  cursor: pointer;
}


.projekt-btn {
  margin-top: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  color: white;
}

.projekt-btn:hover {
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  padding-bottom: 1px;

  cursor: pointer;
}

.footer-left {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0%;
}

.footer-center {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.footer-right {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 0;
}

/* NAVIGATION */
nav.menu .current-menu-parent a:link, nav.menu .current-menu-parent a:visited, nav.menu .current-menu-item a:link, nav.menu .current-menu-item a:visited {
  position: relative; }
  nav.menu .current-menu-parent a:link:after, nav.menu .current-menu-parent a:visited:after, nav.menu .current-menu-item a:link:after, nav.menu .current-menu-item a:visited:after {
    position: absolute;
    height: 1px;
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    right: 0;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    margin-top: -2px;  
}
nav.menu li.menu-item {
  margin-right: 0.5em; }
/*   nav.menu li.menu-item:hover {
    position: relative; }
    nav.menu li.menu-item:hover:after {
      position: absolute;
      height: 0.5px;
      background: #fff;
      width: 100%;
      right: 0;
      display: block;
      content: "";
      margin-top: -2px; } */
nav.menu .menu-main_menu-container .menu li.menu-item {
  display: inline; }
nav.menu .menu-main_menu-container .menu li.home {
  display: block; }
  nav.menu .menu-main_menu-container .menu li.home a:link {
    font-family: 'News Gothic W01 Bold'; }
nav.menu .menu-main_menu-container .menu .sub-menu {
  display: none; }
nav.menu .sub-item li {
  display: inline; }

/* PAGE + BLOG*/
/*.content a {
  color: #fff;}*/
.content {
  margin-top: 1.5em; }
  .content h2 {
    font-family: 'News Gothic W01 Bold';
    margin-bottom: 1.5em; }
    .content h2 a:link {
      font-family: 'News Gothic W01 Bold'; }
  .content p {
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
    max-width: 700px; }
  .content ul.page-list {
    list-style: disc;
    margin-left: 1em; }
  .content .post {
    width: 100%; }
    .content .post img.wp-post-image {
      margin-bottom: 1.5em; }
    .content .post p img.alignnone {
      max-width: 55vw;
      height: auto;
      margin-bottom: 0.5em; }
    .content .post .wp-caption {
      font-family: 'LetterGothicW01-Regular';
      margin: 1.5em 0; }
  .content .page {
    position: relative; }
    .content .page .alignnone {
      position: relative;
      width: 100% !important; }
      .content .page .alignnone img {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1000px;
        height: auto; }

/* STUDIERENDE */


.wrapper-studierende {
  margin: 0 0em; }
  .wrapper-studierende .button-group {
    margin: 0 0 1.5em 0; }
    .wrapper-studierende .button-group button {
      background: none;
      margin-right: 1.5em; 
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
      .wrapper-studierende .button-group button:hover {
        position: relative; 
        border-bottom: 1px solid white;
      }
        .wrapper-studierende .button-group button:hover:after {
          position: absolute;
          height: 1px;
          background: black;
          width: 100%;
          right: 0;
          display: block;
          content: "";
          margin-top: -5px; }
      .wrapper-studierende .button-group button:focus {
        outline: 0; 
        text-decoration: none;
      }
    .wrapper-studierende .button-group button.active {
      position: relative; 
      border-bottom: 1px solid white;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
      .wrapper-studierende .button-group button.active:after {
        position: absolute;
        height: 1px;
        background: black;
        width: 100%;
        right: 0;
        display: block;
        content: "";
        margin-top: -5px; 
        text-decoration: none;
      }
  .wrapper-studierende .post {
    width: 23.25%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2.3%;
    margin-bottom: 2.3%; }
    .wrapper-studierende .post h2 a:link {
      font-family: 'News Gothic W01 Bold'; }
    .wrapper-studierende .post:hover h2 a:link, .wrapper-projekte .post:hover h2 a:visited {
      position: relative; }
      .wrapper-studierende .post:hover h2 a:link:after, .wrapper-projekte .post:hover h2 a:visited:after {
        position: absolute;
        height: 1px;
        background: black;
        width: 100%;
        right: 0;
        display: block;
        content: "";
        margin-top: -5px; }
    .wrapper-studierende .post:nth-child(4n+1) {
      margin-right: 0; }

    .wrapper-studierende .post img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;

      transition: all 400ms;
    }

    .wrapper-studierende .post img:hover {
      /*opacity: 0.8;*/
    }

    .wrapper-studierende .post .meta {
      font-family: 'LetterGothicW01-Regular'; }
      .wrapper-studierende .post .meta a:link {
        font-family: 'LetterGothicW01-Regular'; }
  .wrapper-studierende .navigation {
    display: none; }


.content-studierende {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
.content-studierende a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
.content-studierende h2 {
  margin-bottom: 1.5em; 
}

/*  .content-studierende h2 a:link {
    font-family: 'News Gothic W01 Bold'; 
  }*/

.content-studierende .columns {
  margin-bottom: 1.5em; 
}
  .content-studierende .columns p a:link:after {
    content: '\0020\2192'; 
  }
.content-studierende img {
  margin-bottom: 1.5em; 
}

/* PROJEKTE */

.wrapper-offset-fix {
  /*margin: 0 1em;*/
  transform: translate(1em, 0);
}

.wrapper-projekte {
  margin: 0 0em; }
  .wrapper-projekte .button-group {
    margin: 0 0 1.5em 0; }
    .wrapper-projekte .button-group button {
      background: none;
      margin-right: 1.5em; 
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
      .wrapper-projekte .button-group button:hover {
        position: relative; 
        border-bottom: 1px solid white;
      }
        .wrapper-projekte .button-group button:hover:after {
          position: absolute;
          height: 1px;
          background: black;
          width: 100%;
          right: 0;
          display: block;
          content: "";
          margin-top: -5px; }
      .wrapper-projekte .button-group button:focus {
        outline: 0; 
        text-decoration: none;
      }
    .wrapper-projekte .button-group button.active {
      position: relative; 
      border-bottom: 1px solid white;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
      .wrapper-projekte .button-group button.active:after {
        position: absolute;
        height: 1px;
        background: black;
        width: 100%;
        right: 0;
        display: block;
        content: "";
        margin-top: -5px; 
        text-decoration: none;
      }
  .wrapper-projekte .post {
    width: 23.25%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2.3%;
    margin-bottom: 2.3%; }
    .wrapper-projekte .post h2 a:link {
      font-family: 'News Gothic W01 Bold'; }
    .wrapper-projekte .post:hover h2 a:link, .wrapper-projekte .post:hover h2 a:visited {
      position: relative; }
      .wrapper-projekte .post:hover h2 a:link:after, .wrapper-projekte .post:hover h2 a:visited:after {
        position: absolute;
        height: 1px;
        background: black;
        width: 100%;
        right: 0;
        display: block;
        content: "";
        margin-top: -5px; }
    .wrapper-projekte .post:nth-child(4n+1) {
      margin-right: 0; }

    .wrapper-projekte .post img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;

      transition: all 400ms;
    }

    .wrapper-projekte .post img:hover {
      opacity: 0.8;
    }

    .wrapper-projekte .post .meta {
      font-family: 'LetterGothicW01-Regular'; }
      .wrapper-projekte .post .meta a:link {
        font-family: 'LetterGothicW01-Regular'; }
  .wrapper-projekte .navigation {
    display: none; }

.post-link {
  margin-bottom: 1%;
}

.post-link p:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

/* ----------------------------------------------------- smartphonish screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .wrapper {
    margin: 0.5em 0.5em 0 0.5em; }
    .wrapper p, .wrapper .post {
      width: 100%; }
      .wrapper p img, .wrapper .post img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto; }

  .content p img.alignnone {
    max-width: 100% !important; }

  .wrapper-projekte {
    margin: 0 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em; }

  .wrapper-projekte .post {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 1.5em; }

  .wp-caption {
    width: 100% !important; }
    .wp-caption p.wp-caption-text {
      font-family: 'LetterGothicW01-Regular'; }
    .wp-caption img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto; }

  .page img {
    max-width: 100% !important; } }
/* ----------------------------------------------------- desktopish screens */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .content-studierende h2 {
    margin-bottom: 1.5em; }
    .content-studierende h2 a:link {
      font-family: 'News Gothic W01 Bold'; }
  .content-studierende .columns {
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
    max-width: 700px;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3; }
    .content-studierende .columns p {
      margin-bottom: 1.5em; }
  .content-studierende img {
    margin-bottom: 1.5em; }

  .content p img.aligncenter {
    max-width: 55vw !important;
    height: auto; } }
/* -------------------------------- Browser specific CSS */
/* apply only on JavaScript enabled browsers */
/* apply only on Internet Explorer 8 */
/* apply only on Internet Explorer 9 */

/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

I'm aware that this is a very project-specific question but I simply can't make out what is causing this. Huge thanks to anyone who can help me out.

Comment: Seems to go away once the `transition` is removed ...

Comment: @CBroe True... but weird. Any idea why it behaves like this?

Comment: Probably a result of rounding ... dev tools show me these images as `313.641px` wide, so I suppose when calculating opacity, resp. its effect on what is underneath, some rounding to full pixel values must happen ... simply giving the images a background color seems to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because browser is doing [antialiasing](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/antialiasing-101/). Setting `backface-visibility: hidden;` to `.wrapper-projekte .post img` will solve this.

```
.wrapper-projekte .post img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    transition: all 400ms;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This fixed it for me in Chrome.

```
.wrapper-projekte .post img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    transition: all 400ms;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```